# Image cropping and image resizing with Xamarin.Ios

Tags: xamarin, uiimageview, xamarin.ios, aspect-ratio

I need to implement image compressing and maintaining the aspect ratio with Xamarin.iOS. Right now I am using below code to show image from url.

```
uImage.SetImage(new NSUrl(imageUrl));
```

Above code is showing image from url. But images which are displayed are stretched without maintaining aspect ratio.

I need some code to maintain aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `ContentMode` of your `UIImageView` to

- `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFill` Scales the contents to fill the new bounaries of the view, while preserving the aspect ratio.
- `UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit` Scales the contents so that everything is visible, while preserving the aspect ratio.

See visual examples at: https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIViewContentMode/